# Count ways to take atleast one stick

Tags: algorithm

There are N sticks placed in a straight line. Bob is planning to take few of these sticks. But whatever number of sticks he is going to take, he will take no two successive sticks.(i.e. if he is taking a stick i, he will not take i-1 and i+1 sticks.)

So given N, we need to calculate how many different set of sticks he could select. He need to take at least stick.

Example : Let N=3 then answer is 4.

The 4 sets are: (1, 3), (1), (2), and (3)

Main problem is that I want solution better than simple recursion. Can their be any formula for it? As am not able to crack it

Comment: If you have a recursive solution, you're not far from having a dynamic programming solution.

Comment: You could try computing some small terms and searching on OEIS.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You mean find a series ? But i want proof for the same too

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I tried to link to Fibonacci numbers but no success

Comment: It's a variation of fibonnaci with different starting values

Comment: @JuniorCompressor How ? I didnt get you ?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor, what do you mean by different starting values?

Comment: The fibonnaci starts with 1, 1 and continues by adding the two previous values. Actually it's the same starting values if you include the case the user doesn't select any stick.

Comment: Yea, but you can't really start with 0, 1 (if that's what you're suggesting) because the third number (N=3) would equal 1, when it should equal 4. You can think of it like this: It's ok to *not* pick up the last stick only if he has picked up any previous stick, so the last case depends on previous choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost identical to Fibonacci. The final solution is actually `fibonacci(N)-1`, but let's explain it in terms of actual sticks.

To begin with we disregard from the fact that he needs to pick up at least 1 stick. The solution in this case looks as follows:

1. If `N` = 0, there is 1 solution (the solution where he picks up 0 sticks)
2. If `N` = 1, there are 2 solutions (pick up the stick, or don't)
3. Otherwise he can choose to either

   1. pick up the first stick and recurse on `N-2` (since the second stick needs to be discarded), or
   2. leave the first stick and recurse on `N-1`

After this computation is finished, we remove 1 from the result to avoid counting the case where he picks up 0 sticks in total.

Final solution in pseudo code:

```
int numSticks(int N) {
    return N == 0 ? 1
         : N == 1 ? 2
         : numSticks(N-2) + numSticks(N-1);
}

solution = numSticks(X) - 1;
```

As you can see `numSticks` is actually Fibonacci, which can be [solved efficiently](http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-memoized.html) using for instance memoization.

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of sticks taken by Bob be `r`.

The problem has a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) to the number of binary vectors with exactly `r` 1's, and no two adjacent 1's.

This is solveable by first placing the `r` 1's , and you are left with exactly `n-r` 0's to place between them and in the sides. However, you must place `r-1` 0's between the 1's, so you are left with exactly `n-r-(r-1) = n-2r+1` "free" 0's.

The number of ways to arrange such vectors is now given as:

```
(1) = Choose(n-2r+1 + (r+1) -1 , n-2r+1) = Choose(n-r+1, n-2r+1)
```

- Formula (1) is deriving from number of ways of choosing `n-2r+1`
  elements from `r+1` [distinct possibilities with replacements](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139395)

Since we solved it for a specific value of `r`, and you are interested in all `r>=1`, you need to sum for each `1<=r<=n`

So, the solution of the problem is given by the close formula:

```
(2) = Sum{ Choose(n-r+1, n-2r+1) | for each 1<=r<=n }
```

---

**Disclaimer:**

(A close variant of the problem with fixed `r` was given as HW in the course I am TAing this semester, main difference is the need to sum the various values of `r`.

Comment: There are a few problems with this solution. 1) `n-2r+1` becomes negative as `r` approaches `n`. 2) The number of places to put free 0's is wrong, since it makes no difference if you place a free 0 on the left or right of an already placed 0. 3). The best fix for problem 2 that I can come up with is to set the number of free places to r+1, but it still won't work.

Comment: Suppose N=3 and r=1. We get 2 free 0's, but there are 3 ways to place these: 001, 010, 100 and I can't figure out how to adjust the choose-expressions. We can't say choose 2 out of _,_,1,_,_ because 0,_,1,_,0 would be equivalent to 0,_,1,0,_ for instance. As of now I fail to see how this solution could be repaired.

Comment: @aioobe (1) C(k,n) = 0 if k <0, this is intended. (2) It is taken into account in the "choosing with replacements", you only care where you choose '0' relative to the 1's. (3) There is no fix needed. Similarly, choosing 2 out of 1 is 0.

Comment: (3) I think there is a fix needed. Since you say (1) and (2) is not a problem, let's use your formulas: For the case n=3 and r=1, your formula says there should be Choose(n-r+2, n-2r+1) = Choose(4, 2) = 6 solutions, while AFAICT there should be 3 solutions if you have 3 sticks and you should select 1.

Comment: @aioobe In the [bars and stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) terminology - it is equivalent to placing `n-r-(r-1)=n-2r+1` stars between `r` bars (`r+1` slots), For n=3,r=1 we get 2 stars for 2 slots. This is exactly Starts and Bars with n=2,k=2 now, and the answer to it is given by `C(2+2-1, 2) = C(3,2) = 3`, I will work the algebra back tomorrow morning (getting too late for algebra now), maybe I miscalculated something when placing in the formula, but the bijection to bars and stars works here.

Comment: Please do. I see what you're aiming at, but I couldn't fix it myself, so I'm curious if/how it can be done.

Comment: @aioobe OK, I simply forgot a -1 in the stars and bars formula: n stars with k slots is C(n+k-1,k), which is in our case C(r+1 + n-2r+1 -1, n-2r+1) = C(n-r+1, n-2r+1) (I did C(r+1 + n-2r+1,n-2r+1) - forgot -1 there)\

Comment: Ah, I see. Right, now it works nicely :-) I wasn't familiar with the stars and bars so I dug down the wrong hole when trying to fix it. :-)

Comment: @aioobe I am combinatorics and introduction to graph theory TA, so I should be familiar with this :D